# Regex to separate end of string after comma for apache rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-1.3

I have a working rewrite rule which extracts two numeric values as $1:

example URL: http://somedomain.tld/fixedtext-1,2-anytext

```
RewriteRule ^fixedtext-([0-9\,]+).+$ /skript.php?id=$1
```

So id fills up with 1,2 which is fine

I need to add another value at the END of the string, separated by ","

example URL: http://somedomain.tld/fixedtext-1,2-anytext,3

So how is the solution to access "3" as $2?

```
RewriteRule _____________ /skript.php?id=$1&other_id=$2
```

On the other hand, the regex must also work if the last parameter is not given so

/fixedtext-1,2-anytext

should still work.

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^fixedtext-([0-9\,]+).+,([0-9]+)$ /skript.php?id=$1&other_id=$2
```

which only works if the last parameter ist set

**UPDATE:**

Ok, meanwhile I have two solutions, both work on apache 1.3, but not on apache2:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (,([0-9]+))?/?$
RewriteRule ^fixedtext-([0-9,]+) /skript.php?id=$1&other_id=%2 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^fixedtext-([0-9\,]+).+,([0-9]+)$ /skript.php?id=$1&other_id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^fixedtext-([0-9\,]+).+$ /skript.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So there is still a solution needed which works on both apache versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (,([0-9]+))?/?$
RewriteRule ^fixedtext-([0-9,]+) /skript.php?id=$1&other_id=%2 [L,QSA]
```

This matches optional `,number` at the end of URI and passed that to `$2`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I get "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: That was tested rule. Do you have any other rules also?

Comment: yes, but for other URLs. Even if I delete them this does not work so that should no be the cause

Comment: Asi said this is properly tested rule so it has be due to your existing rules out code. For 500 you need to check Apache's error log.

Comment: from the error.log:.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^fixedtext-([0-9,]+).*?(?:,([0-9]+))?/?$'

Comment: Oh it could be due to old Aache version you have since I have Apache 2.2

Comment: Thanks, but this works for 1.3, but not for 2 - updated initial post

Comment: What do you mean by `both work on apache 1.3, but not on apache2`?? You wrote you have `Apache 1.3.29`

Comment: Sorry for this confusion, I'm developing on a old apche 1.3 setup, but the real system is apache2. So it should work on both systems

Comment: Well I have already tested both the rules on `Apache 2.22` myself so rules are definitely working on `Apache 2` What error are you getting in your `Apache 2`?

Comment: Sorry, error in skript, works now as it should with both methods! I tried to use mysql_real_escape_string(_GET[other_id]) which gave me an empty $other_id on Apache2 (which I don't understand anyway)

Comment: Which method is the prefered one?

Comment: Actually it should be: `_GET['other_id'])` I would prefer first version of the rule since that is smaller.